# Fresh turkey cooking for 2 hours but no juices appearing in pan why

Tags: turkey

I have been cooking a fresh 25lb turkey at 350 degrees for 2 hours so far and there are no juices in pan. What’s the reason and is that a problem?

There is no stuffing in turkey and it is not in a cooking bag.

Comment: Is the turkey covered?

Comment: Is the turkey okay now ?

Answer (score 2):

Juices start to build up in the roasting pan fairly late in the roasting process. Turkeys are *big*, and so it takes a while for the inner parts to heat up to the point where they release moisture.

If you are cooking the turkey in an open roasting pan (with no roasting bag or tented foil), it will take longer for juices to start building up, because they will evaporate off the surface of the turkey immediately. Even with tented foil, the high temperature of the roasting pan will delay the appearance of collected juices. A turkey in a roasting bag will show built up juices earliest, but even with a bag it won't happen until the turkey is pretty far into the cooking process.

If the turkey is stuffed, juices will take longer to appear, because the turkey will take longer to cook and some of the juices will be absorbed by the stuffing.

If you're worried about having stuff to baste with: Whether basting is necessary at all is a matter of opinion, but even if you are determined to baste, melted butter will work just fine.

If you're worried about having enough juices to make a good gravy, and you're starting to panic: If you've got the neck and giblets, simmer them in 2 cups of water for as long as you can, ideally with some onions and other vegetables, and the resultant broth will make a fine gravy. For that matter, feel free to break off part of the wings and stick them in the broth too. You can also use chicken stock, either by itself or as a substitute for the water in your broth. I won't tell if you don't.